# unable to bind data with ngForm on radiobuttons

Tags: angular

Can someone please help, I am trying to bind data to the radiobuttons but nothing seems to be output to the questionnaire.value?!

```
<form #questionnaire="ngForm">
   {{questionnaire.value | json}}    
   <div>
      <label>Float label: </label>
      <mat-radio-group ngModel name="answer1" formControlName="floatLabel">
         <mat-radio-button name="answer1" ngModel value="this">This</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button name="answer1" ngModel value="that">That</mat-radio-button>
         <mat-radio-button name="answer1" ngModel value="other">Other</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="answer1" #radioGroup="matRadioGroup">
  <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="this">this</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="that">That</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="other">Other</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-binding-4v8sci?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like below,

```
<form #questionnaire="ngForm">
   {{ selectedRadioValue }}  
   <div>
      <label>Float label: </label>
      <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedRadioValue" name="answer1" formControlName="floatLabel">
      <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="this">This</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="that">That</mat-radio-button>
      <mat-radio-button name="answer1" value="other">Other</mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>
   </div>
</form>
```